# Securing Apache Solr in production

Tags: web-server, search, solr, jetty, web-application-firewall

I am setting up Apache Solr 4.1 that will be used to index data for a web app. Only the web app should have access to the Solr. Users and other clients will not talk directly to Solr.

What are some of the best practices to secure this type of Solr setup?

(we are using Jetty to run Solr)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you are using Jetty, but I have a method using Tomcat that works and will explain below.

Basically, I have given up trying to understand what I perceive as excessively obtuse ways Java web apps protect themselves in Jetty and Tomcat. So I prefer allowing Apache to do the heavy lifting of being the first line of defense against access. Apache is solid and reliable. And if you feel the need for extra security, you can always install tools like [ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org) to make it even more secure.

The key is to create a reverse proxy setup in Apache like so. The code into the Apache config for the host that will have Solr running. I like to have it running off of a subdirectory, so this example uses `/solr` as an example for  the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` settings. First here are the settings to add a trailing slash to URLs so calls to `http://my.server.is.great/solr` get translated to `http://my.server.is.great/solr/`

```
# Settings for adding a trailing slash to the URL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(solr)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Now here comes the `mod_proxy` stuff that works the magic of routing a Tomcat web app to an Apache frontend.

```
# Settings for Solr in Apache
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

    # Proxy specific settings
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        AddDefaultCharset off
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /solr http://localhost:8080/solr/
    ProxyPassReverse /solr http://localhost:8080/solr/

</IfModule>
```

At this point, I would restart Apache and see if that works. If it does, all good! Now the final step is to go into the Tomcat XML file and restrict Solr to respond only to `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` requests by adding `address="127.0.0.1"` to the connector.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                       address="127.0.0.1"
                       connectionTimeout="20000"
                       URIEncoding="UTF-8"
                       redirectPort="8443" />
```

Now this last part? Maybe this is all you need. Maybe you just want that `address="127.0.0.1"` to instead be the machine IP of the one machine who needs access. But then again you are using Jetty so perhaps there is an equivalent way to restrict to one IP in Jetty? Or you could even restrict via IP in the Apache config. Whatever works best.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, use SSL and require authentication for everything.

[For SSL, see the Jetty docs](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+configure+SSL).

[For authentication, there's a good example for Jetty in the Solr docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity#Jetty_example).