# DNS Names for one server which has two apps

Tags: linux

I have two apps running on one Linux server but on different ports. As per my knowledge DNS names are for IP addresses. We can't create two hostnames for one server for different ports.

I want the DNS  names to include ports as well. how is it possible.
If I create a DNS entry for 10.77.70.90 as test.abc.com will my two apps work with this URL
test.abc.com:8080
test.abc.com:8081

Please help
Thanks

Comment: I'd highly suggest using the reverse proxy as EEAA suggests. It keeps everything clean and that way you can centralize parts of all the apps at once (like caching images, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to include port information in DNS - as you know, DNS provides purely layer 3 information, IP addresses only (except for SRV records, which do frequently contain port information, but unfortunately, web browsers don't support SRV records).

Including the port number in your URLs will work fine, though.

An alternative option is to use a proxy (nginx, mod_proxy, etc.) to proxy traffic through to your applications. Using this approach, you could perform mappings such as:

```
http://app1.test.abc.com -> http://test.abc.com:8080
http://app2.test.abc.com -> http://test.abc.com:8081
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache reverse proxying is the way to go.  I answered a similar [question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/473130/securing-apache-solr-in-production/473307#473307).  Using the answer that EEAA gives as here as an example, I would recommend the following.

So basically you have your apps running on the same machine—aka: localhost—but set for different ports: 8080 & 8081. Set those up and make sure they run on those ports. They run fine?  Great! Now set DNS entries to point `app1.test.abc.com` & `app2.test.abc.com` to 10.77.70.90 and on the machine that will host the content for 10.77.70.90 set the following Apache.

First use Apache to setup virtual hosts & enable the modules `proxy` and `proxy_http`:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

Then make sure virtual host support is active somewhere in your main Apache config by looking for the following in `ports.conf` which should be in your standard Apache2 config directory. If it’s not active, there should be some commented out line that reads as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Then set the virtual hosts as follows. This is the virtual host config for `app1.test.abc.com`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName app1.test.abc.com
  ServerAlias app1.test.abc.com

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^app1\.test\.abc\.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://app1.test.abc.com/$1 [L,R]

  <IfModule mod_proxy.c>

    # Proxy specific settings
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
      AddDefaultCharset off
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

  </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

This is the virtual host config for `app2.test.abc.com`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName app2.test.abc.com
  ServerAlias app2.test.abc.com

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^app2\.test\.abc\.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://app2.test.abc.com/$1 [L,R]

  <IfModule mod_proxy.c>

    # Proxy specific settings
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
      AddDefaultCharset off
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/

  </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

All good?  Restart your Apache server & see what pops up when you go to `app1.test.abc.com` or `app2.test.abc.com`.  If all went well your apps on ports 8080 & 8081 should be showing in each URL.